# Is it possible to show webpage in a window from my Chrome extension, only using JS, HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Google Chrome extension.

When the user clicks the extension button, a small window will appear (not `window.open` / pop-up) and will display the web page. I have basic JavaScript knowledge, and I heard it's possible with JavaScript. So, I want to show my website in limited size window. How can I do that in a simple way with JS/HTML/CSS?

An example (not the same thing, but it's close): [A google chrome extension which is showing in a custom window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gjhnlaeccbboacjkdlopcndknlkjmapp)

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a `popup`. Check out the Chrome Extensions getting started tutorial for more info.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

The popup opens an HTML page and resizes to fit your content. So the simplest way to show an external url in a extension popup would be to place an `iframe` in your popup source:

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried that(and failed), but what is the way to show - let's say www.google.com in that "popup" ? I mean; I don't want to parse images in a webpage, I want to show all of the page.

Comment: write anything in the popup.html at that example. ANYTHING. like "Hello World!". delete all the fancy javascript from there.

Comment: @LostInLib Updated my answer to point in you in the right direction

Comment: Just perfect. I solved the question with you help... First, give the size with style tags, then load it with iframe. Perfect. Thank you very much...